# Algorithms with identical code that can achieve different useful goals when applied to different containers

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, stack, queue

Breadth-first search and depth-first search are two algorithms that are the same, except for what they do, and the data structure they use.

Breadth-first search:

```
q := queue
q.append(root node of tree)
while q is not empty:
    n := q.pop()
    if n is the node being searched for:
        return n
    if n has children:
        c := children of node
        for i in c:
            q.push(i)
```

Depth-first search:

```
s := stack
s.append(root node of tree)
while s is not empty:
    n := s.pop()
    if n is the node being searched for:
        return n
    if n has children:
        c := children of node
        for i in c:
            s.push(i)
```

Are there any other algorithms (or data structures) that work like this?

Comment: "two algorithms that are the same, except for what they do, and the data structure they use". How about quicksort and Boruvka's algorithm? I think you want to refine this criterion.

Comment: @Marcin Unless I've misunderstood Boruvka's algorithm, they are different with regards to what they operate on, whereas I meant what they used.

Comment: Yes. Hence my comment.

Comment: ok then, BFS and Prim are the same, they both operate on graphs, and produce trees! :)

Comment: I get what @sweeneyrod means -- if you use the same variable name for both the queue and the stack, say "container", implementation of DFS == implementation of BFS, bar the first line of code. It is indeed interesting that the same code gives you two different algorithms. I don't know of any other examples though.

Comment: Perhaps this question could be reworded as "Identical algorithms that can achieve different useful goals when applied to different containers."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One that comes to mind is Dijkstra's graph search algorithm and A*. They're essentially the same except for how the next iteration of the loop is chosen - Dijkstra's is breadth first - allowing you to find the closest target and A* is heuristic depth first allowing you to find one target with the least iterations (shortest amount of wall-clock time).

In fact, I've seen both implemented with exactly the same code allowing you to run either A* or Dijkstra (or indeed D* or other algorithms) by supplying the appropriate callback for selecting the next node in the list.

Answer (score 2):

There is a continuous family of algorithms, Prim-Dijkstra, that depend on a parameter in the interval [0,1]. When parameter is 0 you get Prim algorithm; when parameter is 1 you get Dijkstra algorithm.

Prim-Dijkstra is useful what you are computing a sub-tree of a graph with 2 conflicting optimization goals: minimization of maximal distance from "source" vertex to multiple "drain" vertices and minimizing the total length of the tree. In practical applications you often want to bound both quantities, so you perform Prim-Dijkstra with an intermediate parameter.